# Blender Particle system within another particle system

Tags: modeling

I want to place trees on a landscape in Blender using a particle system. The problem is that the trees already have a particle system for the leaves, so it does not work together. What can I do to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

By your description, i imagine that the particles or leaves on the tree won't be moving so you can convert that particle system into a mesh and then apply that mesh as a particle object onto the landscape.